# Sharing value between computer and myRio

Tags: labview

I want to share a value on a VI that runs on the computer to a VI that run on myRIO.
I have used global variable and created it in a new VI in my computer section of the myRIO project and use an indicator in a new VI in myRio section, when i run both the value is always zero.
I also tried the shared variable and the value always a zero without a change.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **Network Published** Shared Variable in order to share your variable.

Just some advice, make sure that variable is only being written to in 1 place in your entire system.  You can run into interesting race conditions if multiple pieces of code are writing to the same variable.